# how could I get a statistics of the length of japanese verbs?

Tags: verbs, phonetics, statistics

How can I make statistics of how many syllables a Japanese verb has? I want to statistic 五段 and 一段 verbs, respectively and exclude all the する verbs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not aware of any publicly available statistics already compiled.  There might well be such datasets, I just don't know of any.

There are various publicly available Japanese dictionaries, either bilingual like [Eijirō](https://eow.alc.co.jp/) and [WWWJDIC](http://nihongo.monash.edu/cgi-bin/wwwjdic) (one of the datastores also used by [Jisho.org](https://jisho.org/)), or monolingual like those made available via [Weblio](https://www.weblio.jp/) or [Kotobank](https://kotobank.jp/).  One option would be to find a way to access those public datastores, identify verbs, filter by conjugation type, and count the morae (kana).

I think WWWJDIC might be the easiest to access this way, as I think I remember reading something about that in the [#Dictionary section](http://nihongo.monash.edu/wwwjdicinf.html#dicfil_tag) of their User Guide.

Comment: Note that most online Japanese-English dictionaries like jisho.org are largely based off the publicly downloadable machine-readable JMdict dataset (https://www.edrdg.org/jmdict/j_jmdict.html) so that might be a good place to start..  It does have verbs broken down by type, as well as kana-based pronunciation data which can be easily parsed to count morae, etc (in XML format).

Comment: @Foogod, thank you for the direct link. The WWWJDIC site uses the same datastore, among others.